# make row in modal cliackable

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

**css:**

```
    <style>
    #my-div {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
    a.fill-div {
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    </style>
```

**html:**

```
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
          <div id="my-div">
            <a href="#" class="fill-div">doctor</a>
            </div>  
            <hr>
            <div href="#" >click</div>
            <p> doctor </p>
    </div>
            <hr>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span><p>pharmacist</p>
            <hr>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-store"></span><p>stockist</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

i am making the div "fill-div" clickable. when i hover on the div the div is cliackable leaving a small portion of the div.....is there a better way to make the div clickable and cover the whole div? i want to make it like the one in the pic.also in the pic, how did they put that circle on the right of evry row?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24U8P.png)

Comment: do you look like  http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Super-Simple-Modal-Popups-with-jQuery-CSS3-Transitions/

Answer (score 0):

```
#my-div{ border:1px solid red;}
    a.fill-div {
        display: block;

      padding:20px 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

use padding to do this i created a snippet it may help.

```css
   #my-div{ border:1px solid red;}
    a.fill-div {
        display: block;

      padding:20px 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

```html
<script data-cfasync="false" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script data-cfasync="false" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bsLink">

<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
          <div id="my-div">
            <a href="#" class="fill-div">doctor</a>
          </div>  
            <hr>
            <div href="#" >click</div>
            <p> doctor </p>
    </div>
            <hr>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span><p>pharmacist</p>
            <hr>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-store"></span><p>stockist</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: there is an image for reference! i want it that way....thanx for your input though Gautam!

Answer (score 0):

With only

```css
.panel a#login_pop, .panel a#join_pop {
    border: 2px solid #aaa;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;

    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -ms-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
a#login_pop:hover, a#join_pop:hover {
    border-color: #eee;
}
.overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    bottom: 0;
    cursor: default;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 1;

    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .5s;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s;
    transition: opacity .5s;
}
  .panel a#login_pop, .panel a#join_pop {
  float: left !important;
  }
.overlay:target {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
.popup {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: justify;
    top: 40%;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 10;

    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -ms-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;

    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
    transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
}
.overlay:target+.popup {
    top: 50%;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
.close {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    top: -15px;
    width: 30px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -ms-border-radius: 15px;
    -o-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.close:before {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    content: "X";
    font-size: 24px;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
.close:hover {
    background-color: rgba(64, 128, 128, 0.8);
}
.popup p, .popup div {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.popup label {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 120px;
}
.popup input[type="text"], .popup input[type="password"] {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #999 #ccc #ccc;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -ms-border-radius: 2px;
    -o-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.popup input[type="text"]:hover, .popup input[type="password"]:hover {
    border-color: #555 #888 #888;
}
```

```html
 <!-- panel with buttons -->
        <div class="main">
            <div class="panel">
                <a href="#join_form" id="join_pop">Sign Up</a>
            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- popup form #1 -->
        <a href="#x" class="overlay" id="login_form"></a>
        <div class="popup">
            <h2>Welcome Guest!</h2>
            <p>Please enter your login and password here</p>
            <div>
                <label for="login">Login</label>
                <input type="text" id="login" value="" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" value="" />
            </div>
            <input type="button" value="Log In" />

            <a class="close" href="#close"></a>
        </div>

        <!-- popup form #2 -->
        <a href="#x" class="overlay" id="join_form"></a>
        <div class="popup">
            <h2>Sign Up</h2>
            <p>Please enter your details here</p>
            <div>
                <label for="email">Login (Email)</label>
                <input type="text" id="email" value="" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="pass">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="pass" value="" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="firstname">First name</label>
                <input type="text" id="firstname" value="" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="lastname">Last name</label>
                <input type="text" id="lastname" value="" />
            </div>
            <input type="button" value="Sign Up" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;or&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#login_form" id="login_pop">Log In</a>

            <a class="close" href="#close"></a>
        </div>
```

simple css

Answer (score 0):

thanx guys for all the help! i got it after some experimenting! below is the code!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        #my-div {
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
        }
        a.fill-div {
            display: block;
            padding-top:10px;
            padding-bottom:10px;
            margin-bottom:-14px;
            margin-top:-14px;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            <hr>
              <div id="my-div">
                <a href="#" class="fill-div"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></span>doctor</a>
                </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

        <script>


        </script>

        </body>
    </html>
```

if someone gets it wrong on some browser after tryinh, please notify!
also change padding and see if it works for you!
thanx guys...cheers!